# How can I be in the sudo file on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sudo

Every time I write `sudo spctl --master-disable` on terminal it asked for my password and I type it gives me this error:

```
Wild.ziv is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

"Wild.ziv" is my name then it says that. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Are you an adminstrator?

Comment: What is in the sudoers file?

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you that error because:

- your *specific* username is not configured in the `sudoers` file
- your *specific* user group is not configured in the `sudoers` file
- you are not a member of a group defined in the `sudoers` file.

macOS, by default, configures the members of the `wheel` group to have `sudo` permissions.  All admins are a member of this group.

If you are not an admin, or you have changed your groups associations and/or reconfigured the `/etc/sudoers` file, you will need to make the appropriate changes to grant yourself `sudo` privileges.